# How to pass unique objects from a second model in ListView function to the template django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a blog app in django. For that, I have made a page where all available blogs are listed. I am using generic.ListView view to achieve this. But, I also want to create a writer's section where I can list some details about the writers that have written those blogs. For this, I need to get all the users that have written a blog and then find distinct users from that and list out their username. I have an author field in my Blog model that keeps track of the writer user. How can I get the distinct usernames of these writers and pass it into my template?

Models.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    blog_head = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    blog_header_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/blogs/", null=True, blank=True)
    #blog_content = models.TextField()
    blog_content = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    #blog_summary = models.TextField(max_length=355)
    blog_summary = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='blog_post_likes', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.blog_head
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('blog-full', args=[str(self.id)])
    def blog_likes_count(self):
        return self.likes.count()
```

Views.py:

```
class blogs_getting_Listview(ListView):
    model = Blog
    template_name =  'blogs.html'
    ordering = ["-blog_date"]
    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(blogs_getting_Listview, self).get_context_data()
        authors_id_list = Blog.objects.get(id=id).author
        authors_list = ""
        for author_in in authors_id_list:
            author_obj = User.objects.get(id=author_id)
            authors_list = authors_list + author_obj
        context.update({
            "authors_list": authors_list
            #'more_context': Model.objects.all(),
        })
        print(type(context["authors_list"]))
        return context
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #path('', views.blogs_getting, name='blogs/'),
    path('', blogs_getting_Listview.as_view(), name='blogs/'),
    path('blog/<int:pk>', blogs_getting_Detailview.as_view(), name='blog-full'),
    path('new_blog/', add_blog_view.as_view(), name='add_blog'),
    path('update_blog/<int:pk>', edit_blog_view.as_view(), name='update_blog' ),
    path('delete_blog/<int:pk>', delete_blog_view.as_view(), name='delete_blog' ),
    path('like/<int:pk>', like_view, name='like_blog' ),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

template:

```
{% for author in authors_list %}
            <p>{{ author }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
```

(Here I am trying to render the author objects' queryset on my page.)

Thankful for any help

Comment: You can add objects in the context. 'authors_list.append(author_obj)'

Comment: Hello, @LordPokerFace, Thank you for replying. I tried your solution. But the problem is, the author_obj is not returning a django object. It retruns a dictonary of the keyword "author" and then the author's ID. On the page, I'll need the author's username, bio and Profile pic later. So, it would be better if I can return the whole queryset of author objects and then be able to iterate over that queryset with a for loop. Is this possible? Is it possible that I maybe using the wrong generic view?

Comment: Show me the User model.

Comment: @LordPokerFace, it is the standard django.contrib.auth User model...

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing directly the author entitie:

```
class blogs_getting_Listview(ListView):
model = Blog
template_name =  'blogs.html'
ordering = ["-blog_date"]
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(blogs_getting_Listview, self).get_context_data()

    authors = Blog.objects.get(id=id)

    authors_list = ""
    for author in authors:
        author_obj = User.objects.get(id=author.id)

        authors_list.append(author_obj)

    context["authors_list"] = authors_list
    
    return context
```